# Stuck in glDrawElements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I have a very strange problem.
My game engine performs loading of model asynchronously. After that it is added to the rendering loop.

The problem is that sometimes (and it's absolutely random) after model was loaded the execution freezes at glDrawElements. I don't get any EXC_BAD_ACCESS  or smth like that.

It seems that all execution is performed inside glDrawElements in some infinite loop. Here is the snapshot that I made in profiler:

[image]

Maybe someone knows how glDrawElements works internally and can point me to the possible reason of the problem.

Comment: how many bytes is in the data you are trying to draw with glDrawElements() ?

Comment: @Rookie I can't say, cause it is absolutely random. Sometimes it freezes on chunk that is about 600 bytes and sometimes on much bigger chunk.

Comment: are you using VBO or vertex arrays? if VBO: how much data you had uploaded to the GPU before the freeze? i think you are running out of memory and its trying to render it all but it does it very slowly because of swapping. i dont know how good iphone hardware is so this is all just a guess. also, perhaps tell more details about how you are rendering, best done in code.

Comment: @Rookie no, I'm not using the VBO. It doesn't swap buffers cause it never goes out the glDrawElements

Comment: i meant swapping in the sense of memory from GPU to RAM to HDD Etc.

Comment: Are you following the usual Apple advice re: EAGLSharegroups and transferring assets between threads?

Comment: @Tommy everything connected with OpenGL is performed in the main thread.

Comment: @givi: Did you solve the problem? I have the same issue and can work around it by allocating a larger buffer than required.